# How do I change an image with Javascript based on dropdown selection value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a complete noob with JavaScript, but I have managed to make a form with 4 drop down selection boxes on the left hand side for a user (State, Car, Year, Condition).

The user makes their drop down selections and clicks a `'calculate'` button underneath, which then runs some simple functions based on their input and displays 4 different values on the right hand side of the form.

In the middle of the form is a picture called car1.png which I would like to change based on the value which is returned to Result 3 (ie, `if 0.07 show "car2.png", if 0.06 show "car3.png"`. I have tried everything I can possibly think of and have read through many tutorials on 'if' statements but feel I am looking in the wrong area.

Any ideas how I would go about doing this as simply as possible given my lack of knowledge in this area would be much appreciated.

Here is what I have come up with so far :

```html
<HTML>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function calcform() 
{ 
with (document.form1) 

{ result1.value = +number1.value * .75 * 50}
{ result2.value = +number2.value * 1}
{ result3.value = +number3.value * 1}
{ result4.value = +number2.value * +number1.value}
} 
</script> 

</div>
<div class="span17">
<table><form name="form1" action=""> 

<h4>State :<br/>
<select name="number" id="number1">
        <option value="15">SA</option>
        <option value="16">VIC</option>
                <option value="17">NSW</option>
        <option value="10">QLD</option>
                <option value="19">NT</option>
        <option value="14">WA</option>
    </select></h4><br/> 
 
<h4>Car :<br/>

<select name="number" id="number4">
        <option value="1">Ford</option>
        <option value="2">Nissan</option>
                <option value="3">Toyota</option>
        <option value="4">Holden</option>
    </select></h4><br/> 
 
<h4>Year :<br/>
<select name="number" id="number2">
        <option value="0.1">1980</option>
        <option value="0.2">1981</option>
                <option value="0.3">1982</option>
        <option value="0.4">1983</option>
                <option value="0.5">1984</option>
        <option value="0.6">1985</option>
    </select></h4><br/> 
 
 <h4>Condition :<br/>
<select name="number3" id="number3">
        <option value="0.08">New</option>
        <option value="0.07">Used</option>
                <option value="0.06">Defect</option>
        <option value="0.05">Scrap</option>
    </select></h4><br/> 
 
 
<input type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate" 
onclick="calcform()" /><input type="reset" id="reset" value=" Clear "/></tr>

</span>

<div class="span20">

<br>
<br>
<img src="car1.png">

  </div>

<div class="span15">

<br/><tr><td><h4><strong></strong></h4><br/>
<h4>Result 1:<br /> 
<div class="span15">
<input type="text" id="result1" value="" size="40" /></h4><br/> 
</div>
<h4>Result 2:<br /> 
<input type="text" id="result2" value="" size="40" /></h4><br/> 

<h4>Result 3:<br /> 
<input type="text" id="result3" value="" size="40" /></h4><br/>

<h4>Result 4:<br /> 
<input type="text" id="result4" value="" size="40" /></h4><br/>
</form> </table>    </div>
                   
                    </div>                
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>        
       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `With` part doesn't look like JavaScript.

Comment: How have you looked everywhere to figure this out? Your code doesn't even alter a single image tag? It seems like you want someone to do this for you. It's also kinda vague on the details of how it needs to work.

Comment: Give your image element an `id`. Then use something like `document.getElelementById("ImageID").src = "image_name";` If I understood your requirements correctly, this logic can be added to your `calcform()` function.

Comment: I'm not sure Praveen, I'm new to Javascript as I said and it seemed right to me as I could get the form to calculate how I wanted it to work with later so thought it all must be okay. Even so, isn't there a way to take the option value returned for "result 3" and use it as a trigger or something to change an image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the image do this in JS:

```
function calcform() 
{ 
with (document.form1) 

{ result1.value = +number1.value * .75 * 50}
{ result2.value = +number2.value * 1}
{ result3.value = +number3.value * 1}
{ result4.value = +number2.value * +number1.value}
if(result1.value > 0)
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "image_name1";
if(result2.value == 1)
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "image_name2";
}
```

**Note:**
This "`if()` statements should contain the condition you want to change to each picture."
Also, change "`image_name1`" and "`image_name2`" to the location of the other images you want for each condition. You can also include more conditions.

**Note 2:**
the `with` statement is fine in JS. It indicates that for each of the following blocks {} you will be using the prefix "document.form1.", i.e.:

```
document.form1.result1.value =  ...
document.form1.result2.value = ...
document.form1.result3.value = ...
document.form1.result4.value = ...
```

put this id in your tag img:

```
<img id="myImage" src="car1.png">
```

Comment: THAT'S IT !. Thank you so much for taking the time to do that Joao, it's really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple little script that might help you show how this should all work.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8axe4nu2/1/

**Code Explanation:**

Function to trigger when you click the button, in this case we are just using it to return the results of your click function.. in this case I am just having it alert what car you selected, but you could ideally have this return the image you would like to show to a specific div.

```
function carPicker(carValue){
    alert(carValue);
}
```

This is the part of the script that you should use the click function to build the result you want returned - in this case I look in the option (dropdown) and get the selected value, you would need to do this for each of your options and then return the joined result.

```
$("#carButton").on("click",function(){
    var carValue = $("#carPicker").val();
    carPicker(carValue);
});
```

Comment: This is only meant to get you pointed in the right direction - this is not a complete answer (ie: I didn't write the script you want, but rather am trying to help show you how to fish!)

Comment: Thanks for your time and for your suggestion. I still don't quite understand how this is supposed to integrate into the file I uploaded and what I am trying to do however ?. Again, I'm just a hobbyist so don't work with this type of thing very much, so need to spend more time trying to figure this out I think. :)